# How to use a variable to determine which index in a list to use

Tags: python-3.x, list, index-error

I've been testing a program of mine lately, and each time I've tested it, I've had the same error message:
IndexError: list index out of range
The code is

```
def NewOffer(CurrentOffer, MaximumPrice, y, NoOfBuyers, Buyers):
    x = random.randint(0, NoOfBuyers)
    SelectedBuyer = Buyers[x]
    if CurrentOffer < MaximumPrice[x]:
        CurrentOffer = CurrentOffer + random.randint(1, 500)
        print(str(SelectedBuyer) + " renewed their offer and are now willing to pay £" + 
        str(CurrentOffer) + " for " + str(AuctionedItem))
        x = random.randint(0, NoOfBuyers)
        NewOffer(CurrentOffer, MaximumPrice, y, NoOfBuyers, Buyers)
        time.sleep(3)
```

And the only line that trips up every single time is the ''' SelectedBuyer = Buyers[x] '''. How do i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

It's seems that the Buyers list don't have an element in position x you can check it by

```
Buyers[x] if len(Buyers) >= x else #some value if it's not in the len()
```

or

```
x = random.randint(0, len(Buyers) - 1)
```

To generate a random number that in the length of the Buyers list.
You may need to do the same for `MaximumPrice`

Answer (score 0):

I tried to understand your code and came up with another implementation:

```py
import random
import time

buyers = (
    ("Peggy Carter", 10000),
    ("Phil Coulson", 7500),
    ("Edwin Jarvis", 5000),
    ("Justin Hammer", 2300),
    ("Darcy Lewis", 1750),
    ("Christine Everhart", 6490),
)

auctioned_item = "The Tesseract"
current_offer = random.randint(1, 5000)
print(f"The starting price for {auctioned_item} is £{current_offer}")
current_buyer = None

def auction_rounds(current_offer, buyers):
    current_buyer = None
    outbid = False
    while not outbid:
        (next_buyer, next_maximum) = random.choice(buyers)
        while next_buyer == current_buyer:
            (next_buyer, next_maximum) = random.choice(buyers)
        outbid = current_offer > next_maximum
        if not outbid:
            current_buyer = next_buyer
            yield (current_buyer, current_offer)
            next_offer = random.randint(current_offer, min(current_offer + 500,
                                                           next_maximum))
            current_buyer, current_offer = next_buyer, next_offer
    else:
        print(f'This is too much for {next_buyer}')

for (current_buyer, current_offer) in auction_rounds(current_offer, buyers):
    print(f"{current_buyer} is offering to pay £{current_offer}",
          "for", auctioned_item)
    #time.sleep(3)

if current_buyer is None:
    print("The first buyer wasn't even able to pay the starting price")
else: 
    print(f"Sold! The auction item ({auctioned_item}) is awarded to {current_buyer} for £{current_offer}")
```

I hope this is something like that, that you were looking for.